# Using LINQ to return average of distinct values

Tags: c#, linq

I don't have much experience with LINQ and I'm having difficulties using LINQ to extract the average, mode and median for a column of a ListView based on distinct values in a different column.

For example, consider this data:

```
ReportID  TAT  Col3  Col4  etc...
--------  ---  ----  ----  -------
80424     9    1     7     ...
80424     9    2     3     ...
80424     9    2     2     ...
80423     5    1     5     ...
80425     4    1     5     ...
80423     7    1     4     ...
82541     7    1     5     ...
```

To extract the count of distinct reports that have a TAT (turnaround time) greater than 5 days, I use the following:

```
int countDistinctReports = (from ListViewItem itm in lvList.Items
                            where itm.SubItems[1].Text) > 5
                            select itm.SubItems[0].Text
                           ).Distinct().Count();
```

The value of `countDistinctReports` is 3.

To extract the minimum TAT for these reports I use this:

```
string minVal = (from ListViewItem itm in lvList.Items
             where itm.SubItems[1].Text) > 5
             select itm.SubItems[1].Text
            ).Min();
```

The value of `minVal` is 7.

However, I don't know how to write LINQ expressions to calculate the average, mode and median TAT of distinct reports that have their TAT greater than 5. In the above example, the average should be (9+7+7)/3 = 7.67. The mode should be 7.

Can someone please help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem reproduced and solved, only using linq 1-liners:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow_StatisticsLinq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var reports = new int[][]
            {
                new int[] {80424, 9, 1, 7},
                new int[] {80424, 9, 2, 3},
                new int[] {80424, 9, 2, 2},
                new int[] {80423, 5, 1, 5},
                new int[] {80425, 4, 1, 5},
                new int[] {80423, 7, 1, 4},
                new int[] {80541, 7, 1, 5}
            };

            var reportsTat5Plus = (
                    from int[] r in reports
                    where r[1] > 5
                    orderby r[1] descending
                    select r)
                .GroupBy(r => r[0])
                .Select(r => r.First()); // ensure ids are distinct
            
            var average = reportsTat5Plus.Select(r => r[1]).Average();
            
            var mode = reportsTat5Plus.GroupBy(v => v)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .First()
                .Select(r => r[1])
                .First();
            
            var median = reportsTat5Plus.Count() % 2 == 1
                ? reportsTat5Plus.Skip(reportsTat5Plus.Count() / 2 + 1).Select(r => r[1]).First()
                : reportsTat5Plus.Skip(reportsTat5Plus.Count() / 2 - 1).Take(2).Select(r => r[1]).Average();

            Console.WriteLine($"Average: {average}");
            Console.WriteLine($"mode: {mode}");
            Console.WriteLine($"median: {median}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution though consider making extension methods for Median, Mode to avoid inline complexity and higher durability

Comment: Note that I used one liners just to show that it could be done/how. I wouldn't write code like this for production: too much is happening one one line for my tastes. Extension methods for mode and median are probably a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

For the average there's also a LINQ-method called [`Average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338413(v=vs.110).aspx). However you have to convert your strings to numbers to efficently work with number-arithmetic.

```
var minVal = (from ListViewItem itm in lvList.Items
             where itm.SubItems[1].Text) > 5
             select Convert.ToInt32(itm.SubItems[1].Text)
            ).Average();
```

However there are no such methods for median or mode. You´d have to create you own ones.

E.g. for median:

```
string subList = (from ListViewItem itm in lvList.Items
             where itm.SubItems[1].Text) > 5
             select Convert.ToIn32(itm.SubItems[1].Text)
            ).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
var median = subList[subList.Count / 2];
```

This will first create a list of all your items with a value greater `5` and than take the center one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the GroupBy method.

```
var groups = myList.GroupBy(e=>e.Key);//here key is your TAT
```

Then if you want to count the number of groups:

```
var count = groups.Count();
```

If you want to get the minimum of all groups:

```
var mins = groups.Select(g=>g.Min());
```

If you want to get and keep the key information:

```
var keyedMins = groups.Select(g=>new{K=g.Key,Min=g.Min()};
```

Same for average and other :)